# Svn: How to checkout some directory and still be able to update at root

Tags: svn, branch, repository-pattern, commit, svn-checkout

I have a SVN project at work that looks like this:

**Repository**

```
 project
   |-- docs
   |-- scripts
   `-- app
        |-- trunk
        |-- branches
        |     `-- development
        `-- tags
            |-- Release_1.0
            |-- ...
            `-- Release_5.3
```

I want my working folder like this:

**Working copy**

```
 dir_root
   |-- docs
   |-- scripts
   |-- trunk
   `-- branches
         `-- development
```

I would like to commit some code from "dir_root/trunk" and "dir_root/docs" simultaneously in one commit to have only 1 revision number.

How can I checkout to ignore the "tags" folder and still be able to commit to multiple directories.

**Note**:

- I can't checkout all the repository because "tags" contains too many release.
- I tried to use sparse directories, but it keep giving me this error "**svn: '/dir_root' is not a working copy**" when I try to commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error it looks like each of the folders under `dir_root` was checkout separately.  Thus `dir_root` itself does not correspond to `project` folder in SVN.

You could start by checking out `project` with `--depth immediates` into `dir_root`.  This will create a folder structure similar to the one in SVN in your `dir_root`.  After this you can update the sub-folders you are interested in (i.e. `docs`, `trunk`, etc.).  Once this is done, you can make changes to contents and do a single commit from `dir_root` which contain changes to `dir_root/trunk` and `dir_root/docs`.

Comment: How do I update the files from docs or trunk. I used svn update --depth inifity, but the files in the folders did not updated.

Comment: I tried to do what you told me, but I still can't commit or status from dir_root.
I checked out with depth immediate in dir_root, and updated the docs and trunk with --set-depth infinity. Then each files I modified would not appear in the svn status or svn commit from dir_root. What did I missed?

Comment: Finally I made it work. I checked out "dir_root" using immediates, and then updated "app/trunk" and "app/branches" using --set-depth infinity. I don't know what I did wrong before, but it works now. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a dir with svn:externals with the structure you have mentioned will solve your problem.

Comment: Would I be able to commit my changes by being positioned in dir_root?

Comment: yep, until the whole working copy is in the same repository  repository. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769236/how-can-i-do-a-single-svn-commit-across-multiple-externals-at-the-command-line